# How to use regex to get the numbers out of this type?

Tags: php, regex

I want a regex that will help me to get the 4 numbers before the cc.
The RegEx must contain the `cc` to identify these exact number.

Example:

> 1600cc

Comment: Here's something to cut down your recurring write-regex-for-me questions: http://regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
/(\d{4})cc\b/
```

`\b` ensures that `"cc"` is at the and of the word.

Comment: thank you for this, please let me know how to edit the code by having instead of the `cc` a `cc,`

Comment: The above code will work even for a comma separated list. \b matches word boundaries. From http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html:

"There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:

1)Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
2)After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
3)Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character."
Case 3 matches a word followed by a comma.

Comment: Thank you again, but because in the html code there are `#FFFFcc;` I would like to ignore and get only the type `1600cc,`

Comment: As you can learn with a minimal effort, /(\d{4})cc\b,/ will match all the sequence composed by 4 digits + cc followed by comma.

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/(\d{4})cc/', $string, $match);
```

`$match[1]` will contain the number.

Comment: thank you for this, please let me know how to edit the code by having instead of the `cc` a `cc,`

Comment: Add a comma to the regexp. Isn't it obvious?